# jquery droppable into categories

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

Ok, so the droppable jquery ui thing is a little confusing to me how its supposed to work. Here is what i'm trying to do. i've got 6 divs that represent some sort of item, and they need to be dropped into any of 6 possibly category divs. so you can put all 6 into one, or 1 into each of the 6, etc.

here is html:

```
    <div class='droppable_category'>
      name
    </div>
    <div class='droppable_category'>
      name
    </div>
    <div class='droppable_category'>
      name
    </div>
    <div class='droppable_category'>
      name
    </div>
    <div class='droppable_category'>
      name
    </div>
    <div class='droppable_category'>
      name
    </div>
  </div>



<br class='clear'>
<div id='column_1_count' class='droppable_bucket'>
</div>
<div id='column_2_count' class='droppable_bucket'>
</div>  
<div id='column_3_count' class='droppable_bucket'>
</div>
<div id='column_4_count' class='droppable_bucket'>
</div>
<div id='column_5_count' class='droppable_bucket'>
</div>
<div id='column_6_count' class='droppable_bucket'>
</div>
```

Here is javascript:

```
$( ".droppable_category" ).draggable({ revert: "invalid" });

$( ".droppable_bucket" ).droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
            .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
            .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
    }
});
```

so basically I need to update some hidden field like

```
<input type="hidden" value="0" id="cat1">
```

to the total number of items dropped int the droppable bucket.

So in the end, i will know how many things were put in buckets 1-6.

Any idea on the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle example

Answer (score 0):

It makes life a bit easier if you link the droppable div to the input, like so:

```
<div id='column_1_count' class='droppable_bucket' data-input='cat1'>
</div>
<div id='column_2_count' class='droppable_bucket' data-input='cat2'>
</div>  
<div id='column_3_count' class='droppable_bucket' data-input='cat3'>
</div>
<div id='column_4_count' class='droppable_bucket' data-input='cat4'>
</div>
<div id='column_5_count' class='droppable_bucket' data-input='cat5'>
</div>
<div id='column_6_count' class='droppable_bucket' data-input='cat6'>
</div>
```

Then you can do something like the following:

```
$( ".droppable_category" ).draggable({ revert: "invalid" });

$( ".droppable_bucket" ).droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var currentHeight = $(this).height();
        var relatedInput = $(this).data('input');
        var catCount = parseInt($("#"+relatedInput).val(), 10);
        $( this )
            .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
            .height(currentHeight+25);
        $("#"+relatedInput).val(++catCount); 
    }
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/9s3kc/5/).

### Edit

Based on your comment, you want a lot more flexibility, moving things between buckets, dynamically tracking where things are dragged and dropped, etc. etc.

Using sortable and draggable together then makes a lot more sense.

If you have HTML like so:

```
<div id="fixedDiv">
    <ul id="category">
        <li class="droppable_category">name</li>
        <li class="droppable_category">name</li>
        <li class="droppable_category">name</li>
        <li class="droppable_category">name</li>
        <li class="droppable_category">name</li>
        <li class="droppable_category">name</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="buckets">
    <ul id='column_1_count' class='droppable_bucket' data-input='cat1'></ul>
    <ul id='column_2_count' class='droppable_bucket' data-input='cat2'></ul>
    <ul id='column_3_count' class='droppable_bucket' data-input='cat3'></ul>
    <ul id='column_4_count' class='droppable_bucket' data-input='cat4'></ul>
    <ul id='column_5_count' class='droppable_bucket' data-input='cat5'></ul>
    <ul id='column_6_count' class='droppable_bucket' data-input='cat6'></ul>
    <ul id='column_7_count' class='droppable_bucket' data-input='cat7'></ul>
</div>
```

You can create JavaScript like so:

```
$(function() {
    var transferred = false;
    $('.droppable_category').draggable({
        connectToSortable: '.droppable_bucket',
        helper: 'clone',
        start: function(event, ui)
        {
            $(this).hide();
        },
        stop: function(event, ui)
        {
            if(!transferred)
                $(this).show();
            else
            {
                $(this).remove();
                transferred = false;
            }
        }
    });

    $('.droppable_bucket').sortable({
        connectWith: ".droppable_category, .droppable_bucket",
        receive: function(event, ui)
        {
            transferred = true;
            var targetInput = $(this).data('input');
            var targetCatCount = parseInt($("#"+targetInput).val(), 10);
            $("#"+targetInput).val(++targetCatCount); 
            if (ui.sender.hasClass("droppable_bucket")) {
                var sourceInput = ui.sender.data('input');
                var sourceCatCount = parseInt($("#"+sourceInput).val(), 10);
                $("#"+sourceInput).val(--sourceCatCount);                 
            }           
        }
    });
    
    $( "ul, li" ).disableSelection();
});
```

[Another fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/EAz3G/2/).

Comment: hey thanks a lot for the help on this. i've got a couple problems, and i'm sorry i just can't figure it out. I have 6 hidden fields (column_1_count, column_2_count, etc). The category divs don't have to have any unique value or anything attached to them, they just represent a total number of available items in each category. I also need to be able to "remove" an item from one bucket and put it in another, but the hidden fields should have a total count in each bucket associated with them. so if i drop all 6 of the categories into bucket 1, the hidden field should have val of 6